# How to customize links on writelatex.com?

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

In order to make links visible in my CV, I'm trying to add following :

```
\hypersetup{

    unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue           % color of external links
}
```

But writelatex.com is rendering following error :

```
Undefined control sequence. l.57 \hypersetup {
```

and here are the latex sources of my CV :

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (9/12/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{dan} % Your first name
\familyname{brown} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Somewhere in the planet earth}{X, Y 8657}
\mobile{(06) 65 94 42 87}
%\phone{(000) 111 1112}
%\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\email{x.y@gmail.com}
%\homepage{staff.org.edu/~jsmith}{staff.org.edu/$\sim$jsmith} % The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\extrainfo{30 ans}
\photo[70pt][0.5pt]{xy} % The first bracket is the picture height, the second is the thickness of the frame around the picture (0pt for no frame)
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hypersetup{

    unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue           % color of external links
}


\begin{document}


\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2010--2013}
    {Ingénieur d'Etat en informatique}
    {Ecole Mohammadia d'Ingénieurs}
    {Rabat, Maroc}
    {Option Ingénierie et Qualité Logicielles}
    {}
\cventry{2008--2010}
    {Classes Préparatoires  Mathématiques et Physiques Spéciales}
    {Lycée Omar  Ibn Abdelaziz }
    {Oujda,Maroc}
    {}
    {}
\cventry{2007-2008 :}
    {Baccalauréat sciences mathématiques}
    {lycée Abou Alkhair}
    {Berkane,Maroc}
    {Mention très bien}
    {}

\section{Stages et Projets}

\cvitem{Stages}
{
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Stage 1\textsuperscript{ère} année :} Conception du MCD pour le projet de l'observatoire marocain de l'agriculture, au sein de l'Office Régional de Mise en  Valeur Agricole de la Moulouya, Berkane.
    \item \textbf{Stage 2\textsuperscript{ème} année :} Contribution à l'élaboration d'une \href{https://www.econseilbook.com/}{plateforme d’e-conseil} en JEE 6 au sein de SIS Consultants.
\end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{Projet de fin d'études}
{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2013--Present}
{1\textsuperscript{st} Développeur Java/JavaEE et Administrateur BD}
{\textsc{ANCFCC}}
{Rabat, Maroc}
{}
{Apports à l'équipe :
\begin{itemize}
    \item J'ai aidé à integrer les données Excel des états parcellaires dans le système d'information de l'institution
    \item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Paper jam
        \item Software issues:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Word not sending the correct data to printer
            \item Windows trying to print in letter format
        \end{itemize}
        \item Coffee spilled inside printer
    \end{itemize}
    \item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}
}
{}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

\clearpage

\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} % Letter recipient
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely yours,} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\lipsum[1-3] % Dummy text

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does moderncv automatically load the hyperref package? If not, you will need to put `\usepackage{hyperref}` before the `\hypersetup` command...

Comment: Yes @darthbith it loads hyperref package automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`moderncv` loads `hyperref` and these settings at `\AtEndPreamble{`:

```
\AtEndPreamble{
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% has to be issued before loading hyperref, as to set \thepage and hence to avoid hyperref issuing a warning and setting pdfpagelabels=false
  \RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}% unicode is required for unicode pdf metadata
  \hypersetup{
    breaklinks,
    baseurl       = http://,
    pdfborder     = 0 0 0,
    pdfpagemode   = \pdfpagemode,
    pdfstartpage  = 1,
    pdfcreator    = {\LaTeX{} with 'moderncv' package},
%    pdfproducer   = {\LaTeX{}},% will/should be set automatically to the correct TeX engine used
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksdepth= 2,% to show sections and subsections
    pdfauthor     = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{}},
    pdftitle      = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{} -- \@title{}},
    pdfsubject    = {Resum\'{e} of \@firstname{}~\@lastname{}},
    pdfkeywords   = {\@firstname{}~\@lastname{}, curriculum vit\ae{}, resum\'{e}}}}
```

Hence you have to use `\hypersetup` after `\begin{document}` or use it with `\AtBeginDocument{` like the following:

```
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        unicode=true,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
        linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
        citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
        urlcolor=blue           % color of external links
    }
    }
```